# Commensurable, Quasi-Isometric and Finitely Generated Groups

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, group-actions, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

*Metric Spaces of Non-Positive Curvature*,
Book by *André Haefliger* and *Martin Bridson*, page $141$.

Two groups are said to be **Commensurable** if they contain isomorphic subgroups of finite index. Commensurable groups are **Quasi-isometric**.

The problem is two commensurable groups need not be finitely generated and the concept of quasi-isometric is only for finitely generated groups (Caylay graphs).

Comment: Yes you want f.g. groups. Quasi-isometries make sense between arbitrary metric spaces and the word metric makes sense for any group with a generating set, the problem is that non f.g. groups don't have a well defined quasi-isometry class.

Comment: One way to state this more generally is: let $(G,d)$ and $(H,d')$ be metric groups. Suppose that $G_1\leq G$ and $H_1\leq H$ are (quasi) isometric (in the induced metrics) finite index subgroups, then $H$ and $G$ are quasi-isometric (wrt the fixed metrics $d,d'$)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a generalization to arbitrary groups.

Say that $f:G\to H$ is a coarse map if for every finite subset $F$ of $G$ there exists a finite subset $F'$ of $H$ such that $f(gF)\subset f(g)F'$ for all $x\in G$.

This is stable under composition.

Say that two maps $f,f':G\to H$ are equivalent ($\sim$) if there exists a finite subset $F$ of $H$ such that $f'(g)\in f(g)F$ for all $g\in G$.

Say that $f$ is a coarse equivalence is there exists $f':H\to G$ another coarse map such that $f'\circ f\sim \mathrm{Id}_G$ and $f\circ f'\sim\mathrm{Id}_H$.

Note that these are maps inducing an isomorphism in the category whose objects are groups and arrows are coarse maps modulo $\sim$. In particular, the existence of a coarse equivalence is an equivalence relation between spaces.

Alternatively, a coarse map $f:X\to Y$ is a coarse equivalence if and only if for every finite subset $F$ of $H$ there exists a finite subset $F'$ of $G$ such that for every $g\in G$ we have $f^{-1}(f(g)F')\subset gF$, and there exists a finite subset $F'$ of $H$ such that $f(G)F'=H$.

It is not hard to prove that a coarse equivalence between finitely generated groups is the same as a quasi-isometry. Also, if two groups are coarsely equivalent and one is finitely generated, then so is the other one.

A group homomorphism $G\to H$ is always a coarse map (clear), and is a coarse equivalence iff it has finite kernel and image of finite index. In particular, commensurable (arbitrary) groups are coarsely equivalent.

Comment: PS coarse maps can be defined between metric spaces, in which case (taking a left-invariant proper metric on the group) this encompasses the case of *countable* groups above. To encompass all groups, one needs Roe's notion of coarse structure (this is, roughly speaking, a structure on a set that gives a meaning, for points $x_i,y_i$, to "$x_i,y_i$ are at bounded distance". In a group, for the left coarse structure, this just means that $x_i^{-1}y_i$ (eventually) remains in a finite set.